# Missing output when Generating JavaDoc on Eclipse Mars.1

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

I am working on Eclipse Mars.1. When I hit the "Generate JavaDoc" button (under `Project > Generate JavaDoc...`) the command works well and the javadoc is generated.

The problem is that it does not show the output of the command. On previous versions of Eclipse, the console would show the output, telling me about warnings and errors, and so. I really need to know about such things, but I can't get the Eclipse console to show something.

I am using Eclipse Mars.1, Windows 10 and Java 1.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the console output showing up again. I don't know exactly what I have done, but it seems that checking the option `Open generated index file on browser` has done the trick. Other things that I have done include checking every class and put javadoc comments manually, but I don't think it is necessary because when I ran the command and the console wrote the output, it gave me errors...

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

It is a defect from Eclipse.
The console is not initialized if you start Eclipse and the first thing to do is to generate the documentation.
The solution is to **run first the application**. The JavaDoc errors will appear from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help someone else outside there who came here and find that the accepted answer did not match his/her problem like I did.

I have solved the problem just by open <strike>the other</strike> Java Stack Trace console (the toolbar is at the top right of the terminal), <strike>Maven console for example,</strike> and re-run the Generate Javadoc.. Now, the console output should showing up again.

Hope this helps.